# How to ignore backspace when using readLine() in Java?

Tags: java

For example, I want to use a keyboard to input a name, but I made a mistake and would like to correct it. So I use the backspace key and try to delete the character I entered. It seems it took the backspace as an input as well.
How can I ignore the backspace and correct my input?

Comment: is it took the backspace as an input? is that in the java console?

Comment: I use System.in

Comment: Are you using Scanner or BufferReader?

Comment: use Scanner object

Comment: I use BufferedReader. So I should use Scanner instead?

Comment: You won't have that issue by using the Scanner Object

Comment: Please post your code.  I don't think you should get that issue with `BufferedReader` either, or with any *normal* input method.  You pretty much have to be looking for individual key presses in order for a backspace not to work as a backspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ScannerObject if you are getting the input from keyboard

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }

    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: It is so weird that even I type "j", it gives j^?j, and if I enter the backspace key, it gives me "^?". But other inputs are fine.

Comment: @Jie What happens if you type, say, "abc", CONTROL-H, "def"?  Does it backspace then?  I'm wondering if there's a disconnect between the OS and the keyboard.  Historically, some OS's have used DEL (ASCII 127) to erase the last character, which shows up as `^?`, and some have used BS (ASCII 8), which you get with control-H.  These days, modern OS's understand "key presses" instead of ASCII codes.  But if you're using one OS to log in remotely to some other machine running a different OS, it seems possible that the problem is a mismatch in what character it expects to be the "backspace".

Comment: @ajb You are totally right. I edit my file in spacemacs, and also use the shell inside it. Then I use ssh to remotely run the code. Both give me the same errors. After reading your comment, I changed to use the terminal directly, it works, even with BufferedReader class. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use console instead

```
  Console c = System.console();
    if (c == null) {
        System.err.println("No console.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String login = c.readLine("Enter your login: ");
```